# How to setup and use the vim-rails plugin?

Tags: vim, rails, vim-plugin

How do I setup and use the `vim-rails` plugin?

I have installed it by running `sudo apt-get install vim-rails`. What do I do next to enable the plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `vim-addon-manager` to enable the plugin. To do so, open your terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd> and execute the following command.

`vim-addons install vim-rails`